# Get only website name from URL-string

Tags: php, url

I haven URL-string like http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/clean/logo.png, how can I extract only google.com from the URL? I want to do this on all my URL-strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try function [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
<?php
$url =  'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/clean/logo.png';
$array = parse_url($url);

echo $array['host'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>
```

Comment: This isn't going to work as he I doubt he is running his script on googles' servers...

Comment: but why ou give me minus reputations ? the answer was correct!

Comment: As you can see this answer doesn't have a negative score. Which means only one thing..... I didn't down vote your answer.

And no, your answer is not correct to what the OP is asking. Sorry to be blunt but there it is.